# SQL Column concatenation in Where Clause with Like

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, concatenation

**Problem**

i have user table consist of columns firstname and lastname. My search input may have firstname+lastname .It may combined for search

**I tried like**

```
SELECT 
last_name, 
first_name,
from 
user
WHERE
last_name+first_name LIKE "%MY input%"
```

But It was not working. How to resolve this?

Comment: `last_name + ' ' + first_name LIKE "%MY input%"`

Comment: Thanks i got resolved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT last_name,first_name
from   user
WHERE  contact (last_name,'',first_name) LIKE "%MY input%";
```

Comment: `Concat` was introduced in *SQL Server 2012*?